# Bootstrap multi select list doesn't open for Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

The multiselect form is being rendered properly but it only shows the first option which is none selected. When I click on it, it does not show the list of skills to select from.

I have installed the bootstrap-multiselect-rails gem. I have added *= require bootstrap-multiselect to application.css and //= require bootstrap-multiselect to application.js.

tasks/new.html.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
<h2>Create Task</h2>
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>

  <div class="space">
  <p>Skills:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="space">
    <label id="example-getting-started"">
        <%= f.collection_select :skill_ids, @skills, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
    </label>
  </div>


  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn button" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: what is in `@skills`?  sounds like that might be empty

Comment: Skill is a model. @skills is the list of skills.  I can see all the skills when I don't add the bootstrap multi select scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`<label id="example-getting-started"">`

You are calling the multiselect on the label, you need to call it on the `select` element.  Figure out what the ID of that is and call multiselect on it.

Comment: Ok. I tried changing it to <%= f.collection_select :course_ids, @courses, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true}, id: "example-getting-started" %> but now rails throws an error saying wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 4..6)

Comment: that's not how [`collection_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) works.  ID would be an HTML option, so you need to add it to the html options hash.  Try this: `<%= f.collection_select :course_ids, @courses, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true,  id: "example-getting-started"} %>`

Comment: Did you remove that ID from the label when you added it to the select?  also can you confirm that the select actually has that ID in the inspector and that there's no console errors?

Comment: I did remove the ID. but the console says that the files I added are not found

Comment: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  for each of the links and scripts

Comment: but I can see the form render correctly and the script $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    }); seems to work

Comment: maybe could there be a problem since I added *= require bootstrap-multiselect to application.css and //= require bootstrap-multiselect to application.js.